# Creation of an Azure Automation Connection via PowerShell - error 'account was not found'

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation

I am running the following PowerShell code:

```
Get-AzureRmAutomationAccount `
    -ResourceGroupName $AUTOMATION_ACCOUNT_RESOURCE_GROUP `
    -Name $AUTOMATION_ACCOUNT_NAME 

New-AzureRmAutomationConnection 
    -ResourceGroupName $AUTOMATION_ACCOUNT_RESOURCE_GROUP `
    -AutomationAccountName $AUTOMATION_ACCOUNT_NAME `
    -Name $ConnectionAssetName `
    -ConnectionTypeName AzureServicePrincipal `
    -ConnectionFieldValues $ConnectionFieldValues
```

The `Get-AzureRmAutomationAccount` displays details of the automation account, but `New-AzureRmAutomationConnection` (although using exactly the same parameter values) throws the following error:

```
New-AzureRmAutomationConnection : The Automation account was not found.
At line:2 char:1
+ New-AzureRmAutomationConnection -ResourceGroupName $AUTOMATION_ACCOUN ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmAutomationConnection], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Automation.Cmdlet.NewAzureAutomationConnection
```

Any suggestions what I may be missing are appreciated! :)

Comment: Just for testing purposes, first list all the accounts using `Get-AzureRmAutomationAccount -ResourceGroupName $AUTOMATION_ACCOUNT_RESOURCE_GROUP` and check that the actual account name that you are using exist on that list :)

Comment: Yes, it's there. I get the same information as by running Get-AzureRmAutomationAccount `
    -ResourceGroupName $AUTOMATION_ACCOUNT_RESOURCE_GROUP `
    -Name $AUTOMATION_ACCOUNT_NAME

I also tried replacing variables with hard coded values, the same result. I think I am missing something :D

Comment: Another test...what if you run the first instruction in just one line and without the backticks?

Comment: The same result :) Actually initially it was in one line, I have added backticks so that it looks better on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is misleading, the error you are most likely seeing is related to a bad field. Run the cmdlet with debug to see the value is it failing on. You will have to scroll up a bit to find the exception in the body.

Ensure you have your cert thumbprint, sub id, tenant, and app id. I just tested with the following and it worked as expected. (replaced my values of course). Hope this helps!

```
New-AzureRmAutomationConnection `
    -ResourceGroupName TestAzureAuto `
    -AutomationAccountName TestAzureAuto `
    -Name "MyAsset2" `
    -ConnectionTypeName AzureServicePrincipal `
    -ConnectionFieldValues @{"CertificateThumbprint"="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000";"SubscriptionID"="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";"ApplicationId" = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"; "TenantId" = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" }
```